# How to export QR code images in an excel file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, image, qr-code

I am trying to convert product codes to QR codes and export them in an Excel file however the QR code outputs are as string types.

How can I export QR code images in an excel file using python?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode
import xlsxwriter
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def create_qr_code(product_code, product_name, file_path):
    # Create QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(f"{product_code}, {product_name}")
    qr.make(fit=True)

    # Create an image from the QR code
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    return img

# Read data from an Excel file using pandas
# Get the path to the Excel file
file_path = r'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\project\PMS-231116-BME-code.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=2)

# Create QR codes for each product in the data
product_codes = []
qr_images = []
for index, column in data.iterrows():
    product_code = column['Asset no.']
    product_name = column['Equipment name']
    img = create_qr_code(product_code, product_name, file_path)
    product_codes.append(product_code)
    qr_images.append(img)

new_data = {'Product name': product_codes, 'Qr code': qr_images}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

# Create a new Excel file and write the DataFrame to it
file_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/project/output_data.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path) as writer:
    new_df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

how can i fix this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl to insert image into excel. And also write data into it. This is code to show you how to use it in your program. You can give it a try.

```
import openpyxl as op
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb = op.Workbook()
    ws = wb['Sheet']
    YourData = [{'Product name': 1234, 'Qr code': img}]
    for data in YourData:
        ws.append(data['Product name'])
        ws.add_img(img,'B1')
    wb.save('qrcode.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to save image directly, technically you'd have to save the image first then insert it.
For your actual code to work you can try switching to the Openpyxl engine so actually saving the image first can be skipped.

This is an example of 'how to' incorporating your code using Pandas and ExcelWriter, however a simpler option like that proposed by @SuNing possibly is the better way depending on what your needs are.

I'm not sure how you envisaged the Excel sheet to look given the QR codes are likely to be larger than a cell row unless you plan to resize the row height and/or image however for this example code I wont change how the Product code it's written using 'to_excel' to each consecutive row in column A. I do not include the images in the 'new_data' dataframe, these are added separately using Openpyxl 'add_image' after conversion.
We loop your 'qr_images' list, convert each PILImage to an image stream which Openpyxl can use.

For the example I have increased the row height and reduced the QR image size somewhat.

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as oImage


def create_qr_code(product_code, product_name, file_path):
    # Create QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(f"{product_code}, {product_name}")
    qr.make(fit=True)

    # Create an image from the QR code
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    return img


# Read data from an Excel file using pandas
# Get the path to the Excel file
file_path = 'codes.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=2)

# Create QR codes for each product in the data
product_codes = []
qr_images = []
for index, column in data.iterrows():
    product_code = column['Asset no.']
    product_name = column['Equipment name']
    img = create_qr_code(product_code, product_name, file_path)
    product_codes.append(product_code)
    qr_images.append(img)

new_data = {'Product name': product_codes, 'Qr code': ''}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

# Create a new Excel file and write the DataFrame to it
file_path = 'output_data.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    new_df.to_excel(writer, index=False) 
    workbook = writer.book  # Openpyxl Workbook 
    worksheet = workbook.active  # Openpyxl worksheet 
    for row, img in enumerate(qr_images, 2):
        ### Convert image to PNG for Openpyxl use
        img_stream = BytesIO()
        img.save(img_stream, format='PNG')
        img_openpyxl = oImage(img_stream)

        ### Resize image
        img_openpyxl.width = 100
        img_openpyxl.height = 100

        ### Set a row height
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 70

        ### Add Image to sheet
        worksheet.add_image(img_openpyxl, f'B{row}')
```

Example Output
[image]

Comment: thanks, sir!!!! thanks, sir!!!! It took me nearly a day to try to solve :((

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel but similar as for LibreOffice it should work, too:

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode
import shutil
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image


file_in = r'PMS-231116-BME-code.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_in)
shutil.copyfile(r'PMS-231116-BME-code.xlsx', 'output_data.xlsx')
file_out = 'output_data.xlsx'


def qr_code(qr_data):
    # Create qr code
    image_path = f"qrcode_qr_{index}.png"
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,box_size=1,border=2)
    qr.add_data(qr_data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    img= img.save(image_path)
    return image_path

def write(f_out, qrc, idx):
    wb = load_workbook(f_out)
    ws = wb.active
    qr_im = Image(qrc)
    ws.add_image(qr_im,f'D{idx+2}')
    ws.row_dimensions[idx+2].height = 50
    ws.column_dimensions['C'].width = 50  
    wb.save(f_out)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    input_data = index, row
    qr_c = qr_code(input_data)
    write(file_out, qr_c, index)
```

Output:
[image]

**Option2** Pandas used instead of openpyxl and the pictures are encoded as base64. Base 64 encoded image can be inserted as text to pandas and rendered in html. If you have jupyter you can export to html what could be opened in Excel easily:

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import HTML


file_in = r'D:/Daten/Programmieren/stackoverflow/QR_Code/PMS-231116-BME-code.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_in)


def qr_code(qr_data):
    # Create qr code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,box_size=1,border=2)
    qr.add_data(qr_data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    fake_file = BytesIO()
    img.save(fake_file, "png")
    b64 = base64.b64encode(fake_file.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    #print(b64)
    im = Image.open(fake_file)
    im.show()
    return '<img width=100 src="data:image/png;base64,'+b64+'">'
    


qr_images = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(index,"\n", row)
    b64 = qr_code(row)
    qr_images.append(b64)
    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(qr_images, columns = ["QR"])
df2 = pd.concat([data, df1], axis=1)

table = HTML(df2.to_html(escape=False))
html = table.data
with open("D:/Daten/Programmieren/stackoverflow/QR_Code/output.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Output (Jupyter):
[image]